# Android Best Practice for 6 Lists of Related data - Dashboard, horizonatally scrollable TabHost, or Other

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-tabhost, dashboard

I have a series of 6 lists of related data.  Really, they are the same set of data split out by a status flag into 6 different "Queues".  In my android application I have a [dashboard pattern](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/twitter-for-android-closer-look-at.html) for my main menu, which has an option for the queues.  The tab strip is too small to have 6 options on it, so I would either have to have a horizontal scroll view around my tabhost (which I can't seem to get to work easily), or I need to find another way.  From what I've seen, if I need that many tabs, I should be looking at a dashboard design pattern.  Is it acceptable to have a nested dashboard?  What is the best practice here?

Comment: for reference, I am getting rid of my tabs and moving to using an ActionBar (https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar) and QuickActions (http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/)

Comment: Are there rich visual representations of each of these lists? I might consider using the Carousel pattern ( http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/carousel ) in this case.